# Getting a large dict from a column of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that contains dictionaries of bags of words (key = word, value = count in the document). Each dict is unique (the documents are unique), but there are probably some shared keys.

I want to get a histogram of the counts of all of the words in the corpus. In other words, I need to get all of the unique keys for all rows and then sum up their values.

The dictionary part is throwing me off. How can I do this?

Comment: If you used `collections.Counter` for your counts, rather than plain dictionaries, you could simply add them together.  You could probably just apply `sum()` to the entire column to get the combined counts.

Comment: Maybe a loop through all dictionaries, with an inner loop through the keys for each dictionary. Put these all into a new dictionary, where if the key is new, it sets the value to the count, otherwise it adds to the existing count for that key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
big_dict = {}
for d in your_dataframe['your_column']:
    for k in d:
        if k in big_dict:
            big_dict[k] += d[k]
        else:
            big_dict[k] = d[k]
```